# sklearn clustering extracting id for each label in cluster

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

Hello I am learning how to use the Scikit-learn clustering modules right now. I have a working script that reads in a pandas dataframe.

```
df=pd.read_csv("test.csv",index_col="identifier")
```

I converted the dataframe to a numpy array

```
array=df.to_numpy()
```

Then implemented the clustering and plotted as so:

```
km=KMeans(n_clusters=25,init="random",n_init=100,max_iter=1000,tol=1e-04, random_state=0)
##get cluster labels
y_km=km.fit_predict(array)
###To plot use PCA function
pca=PCA(n_components=3)
pca_t=pca.fit_transform(array)

####
u_labels=np.unique(y_km)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

for i in u_labels:
    ax.scatter3D(pca_t[y_km == i , 0] , pca_t[y_km == i , 1],pca_t[y_km == i , 2],  label = i)
ax.legend()
```

This all outputs a plot that looks like this:

[image]

I want to try and get a final output that ouputs a dictionary or text file of some sort that tells me what cluster each identifier is in based on the row ids of the original array. I was having trouble figuring out how to maintain that information though. I tried seeing if I could use the pandas Dataframe.to_records() function which maintained the dtypes but couldn't figure out how to translate that to what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y_km` contains your labels in the same order as the rows in your pandas dataframe. example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two','two'],
'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
},
index =  ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 't']
)

y_km = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(pd.DataFrame(y_km, df.index))

   0
x  1
y  2
z  3
q  4
w  5
t  6
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly the information I needed! I wasn't sure if order was maintained like this in the numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
print(y_km.labels_)
```

This should give you a list of label for each point.

See the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeanshttps://) for KMeans.